# Using Blazor as the framework to develop SPFx webparts

Tags: spfx

I am wondering if someone knows if this is being attempted anywhere. Currently React seems to be the one appearing most in my searches. I have learned and developed on Microsoft Blazor yet I do not see it being used to develop for Microsoft Sharepoint SPFx projects.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the framework is based on JavaScript:

[Overview of the SharePoint Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview#key-features-of-the-sharepoint-framework)